# Sqflite: Como obtener todos los datos de una columna que cumpla con un nombre

Tags: android, sql, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

Estoy aprendiendo SQFLITE con flutter, y he creado una tabla llamada `todos` en donde ya tengo varios inserts.

Me gustaría crear una función para obtener en una lista los resultados obtenidos de una consulta específica a una columna llamada `categoria`, es decir, me gustaría obtener en una lista todas las categorías que sean por nombre `"TIC"`.

Esto es lo que tengo.

mi clase DatabaseHandler:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'lista_model.dart';

class DatabaseHandler {
  Future<Database> initializeDB() async {
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'mytodos2.db'), //join(path, 'tododatabase.db'),
      onCreate: (database, version) async {
        final String sql = ''
            'CREATE TABLE todos ('
            ' id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'
            ' title TEXT,'
            ' entidad TEXT,'
            ' categoria TEXT,'
            ' emision TEXT,'
            ' img TEXT,'
            ' url TEXT,'
            ' description TEXT'
            ')';

        await database.execute(sql);

            final String addTodo = ''
                'INSERT INTO todos(title, entidad, categoria, emision, img, url, description) 
         VALUES ("nombre todo1" , "enti todo1", "TIC", "emision1", "img1", "url1", "desc1"),
        ("nombre todo2" , "enti todo2", "TAC", "emision2", "img2", "url2", "desc2"),
        ("nombre todo3" , "enti todo3", "TIC", "emision3", "img3", "url3", "desc3")';

    wait database.execute(addTodo);

        deleteDatabase("mytodos1.db");
      },

      version: 1,
    );
  }

// Make the inserts
  Future<void> inserttodo(todo todo) async {
    final db = await initializeDB();

    await db.insert(
      'todos',
      todo.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  /*Calling the table of the bd*/
   Future<List<todo>> todos() async {
        final db = await initializeDB();
        final List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryResult = await db.query('todos');
        return queryResult.map((e) => todo.fromMap(e)).toList();
      }

`//AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO FILTRAR LOS QUE CONTENGAN LA PALABRA 'TIC' DENTRO DE LA COLUMNA` 'categoria':

  _query() async {

    final db = await initializeDB();
    //db.rawQuery('SELECT categoria FROM todos WHERE categoria="TIC"');

    // get single row
    List<String> columnsToSelect = ['categoria'];

    List<Map> result = await db.query(
      'todos', //selecciona la tabla
      columns: columnsToSelect, //selecciona columna, en este caso = categoria
      where: 'TIC', //donde categoria sea "TIC"
    ); 

    // print the results
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));

    return result; //retorno la lista filtrada para recibirla en otra clase o pantalla
      }
}
```

Por lo tanto he intentado dicho metodo pero

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que le pasas el `where` (que son las columnas), debes usar el `whereArgs` que vienen a ser los argumentos.

```dart
 where: 'categoria = ?',
 whereArgs: ['TIC'],
```

En `columns` van las columnas que quieres obtener en el resultado.

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación que ofrece el plugin, está muy completa: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/README.md