# Flutter: Como mostrar varias cards estáticas en forma row dentro de column

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy aprendiendo flutter, y me gustaria mostrar en pantalla varias cards o tarjetas dentro de un Scrollable vertical. Es decir, quiero que salgan dos colunas de tarjetas y que al tocar cada una de ella me lleve a otra pantalla correspondiente.

En otras palabras quisiera lograr algo como esto, simplemente 2 columnas de cards y que sea scrolleable hacia abajo porque quiero agregar mas cards con el tiempo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria saber que libreria o por donde empezar, gracias.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class CardsCategorias extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardsCategorias({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CardsCategorias> createState() => _CardsCategoriasState();
}

class _CardsCategoriasState extends State<CardsCategorias> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Todas las Categorias",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0, /*fontWeight: FontWeight.bold*/
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(

      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Antes de crear nuevas preguntas, responder las anteriores https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/522546/66190

Comment: Si quieres hacer scroll supongo que será vertical, tendrás que usar un SingleChildScrollView y dentro como hijo una column. Ahora dentro de esa column tienes n hijos unos son row y otros containers o lo que quieras pintar.
Un Saludo,